# Apache Pig, including endpoint for DaysBetween

Tags: apache-pig

How can I verify if the DaysBetween() function in pig has considered the ending point or not? For example, if I try

```
grunt> DaysBetween(ToDate(1994-12-04, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), ToDate(1994-12-04, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

I want to see if it returns me a 1 or 0.
However, it gives an error message of

```
mismatched input '-' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

So what does this message mean? Does the function consider ending point or not; or is there an built-in option for that?

The same question also applies to the function of SubtractDuration().

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your statement - you need to surround both instances of `1994-12-04` in quotes (so `'1994-12-04'`).